# count number of element in list excluding certain element

Tags: python

I have python list like this:

```
data = ['A1A1.AA1', 'A1A1.AB1', 'A1A1.AC1', 'ABB.A1A']
```

I wish to ignore element whose second last char is A or last char is A. So, in the above list "A1A1.AA1" and "ABB.A1A" should be ignored.

Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> data = ['A1A1.AA1', 'A1A1.AB1', 'A1A1.AC1', 'ABB.A1A']
>>> [item for item in data if not re.search(r"A.?$", item)]
['A1A1.AB1', 'A1A1.AC1']
```

**Explanation:**

```
A   # Match A
.?  # Match 0 or 1 characters (any character)
$   # Match the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a list comprehension to filter the item that matches your condition(s).

```
result = [ element for element in data if element[-1] != 'A' and element[-2] != 'A' ]
```

Comment: Yes you're right! I've already fixed that in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use [itertools.filterfalse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) following way

```
import itertools
def unwanted(x):
    return x[-2] == 'A' or x[-1] == 'A'
data = ['A1A1.AA1', 'A1A1.AB1', 'A1A1.AC1', 'ABB.A1A']
print(list(itertools.filterfalse(unwanted, data)))
```

output

```
['A1A1.AB1', 'A1A1.AC1']
```

`[-1]` means last element, `[-2]` means second last. This solution assumes that every element is at least 2 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use square brackets to access the indexes of strings. -1 would be last, -2 would be 2nd to last, etc... This example was made in Python 3.9.2 64-bit

```
    data = ['A1A1.AA1', 'A1A1.AB1', 'A1A1.AC1', 'ABB.A1A']
    ct = 0

    for item in data:
        if (item[-1] != 'A' and item[-2] != 'B'): ct += 1

    print(ct)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
new_data = []
for d in data:
    if (d[-1] != "A") and (d[-2] != "A"):
        new_data.append(d)
len(new_data)
```